# Different style for anchor tag when clearing the browser cache

Tags: css, caching, anchor

when i click on anchor tag  - a dotted border come around my anchor text. the is is coming in IE7,IE8 and firefox. I have used.

> `a{ outline:none; }`

this works as expected.But i need to clear the cache of my browser. Unless and until i don't clear the cache in my browser that dotted line appears around my anchor text.

Could anybody please tell me why always I am required to clear cache everytime to make outline property work. Is there any solution that without clearing the cache that dotted line will disappear.

Comment: Does this happen only on visited links or on all links? Have you tried using `a:link, a:focus, a:visited { outline: none; }`?

Comment: won't outline:none be inherited to a:link, a:focus and a:visited?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add the `a:visited` pseudo-class to in your CSS:

```
a:visited { outline: none; }
```

The `a:visited` style should inherit from the `a` class, but some older browsers like IE6 do not follow this rule ([Source](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?p=2308104#post2308104)). To ensure correct style compatibility with older browsers, it is recommended to define the `a:visited` pseudo-class.

Comment: is that necessary? a:visited will inherit the outline:none from a

Comment: @pixeltocode: I'm not sure if all the browsers inherit from `a` as they should. I'll try some tests... However the problem of the OP seems linked to `a:visited`.

Comment: @pixeltocode: Apparently IE6 doesn't inherit correctly in this case. This is alsoo mentioned in this SitePoint forum post: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?p=2308104#post2308104

Comment: I had also tried this. But still i need to clear cache to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

try using a reset CSS like [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: +1 Yahoo (YUI) have a good reset stylesheet (as do many others), but I also tend to stick with Eric Meyer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get rid of this is to use `a:visited` and/or `a:active` like Daniel Vassallo anwered.

This should fix the problem and still gives visual feedback to users who navigate through all elements with TAB.

Answer (score 0):

i have used..

> a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active{
>     outline:none !important;
>     -moz-outline:none; }

but still i need to clear cache everytime to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overriding the `a:visited` rule. For example if you have more than one style sheet like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-a.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-b.css">
```

On style-a.css we found the following rule:

```
a:visited { color: #00ff00; }
```

And, on style-b.css we have:

```
a:visited { color: #ff0000; }
```

The resulting visited link will be colored Red (#ff0000) the rule found on `style-b.css`, and NOT Green (#ff0000) as found on `style-a.css`

For reference:

> The CSS cascade assigns a weight to each style rule. When several rules apply, the one with the greatest weight takes precedence. -- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade